# Can HTML pages' size get smaller?

Tags: java, android, html

I have about more than 1000 pages to display for Android Mobile App and all of them are in HTML. Each page has a size of about 300KB, is it possible if their size can be reduced?

Comment: Remove a letter, the size will get smaller. What are you asking?

Comment: If you put the html files in the asserts folder inner your android APK the file is automatically zip compressed.

Comment: I thought so, too but it did not work.

Comment: What type of contents are in these files that they are weighing up to 300kb? Are you including images in this size?

Comment: Just text with big font size no image. If I make the font size smaller is it possible to be able to have the "zoom" option for App in the coding?

Comment: Is your app trying to host a webserver on a mobile? And how did you get to 300k, if it is just text? Its like 300 books in there!

Comment: I have no idea how is that big, this is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? http://htmlcompressor.com/compressor.html

Comment: Works but not big difference, I guess this would be my best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some duplicated data among these files?

Maybe, you can separate Visual Structure from Data.

Did you look something about MVC (Model-View-Control) architecture? I think it may introduce a separation of concerns between applications layers.

May you organize your data structure into JSON format and represent it in HTML using some JavaScript parsing?

If you can deploy your data files and deliver it on demand, using some cache layer inside your application, you can improve data transmission between client/server using compression (gzip,deflate,...) and install some filters on server side for code cleanup (mod_pagespeed) and minifiers. They can help you to reduce unnecessary characters/code.